# How to Create list of Multiple Combinations using Dict in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to form a list of combinations in a given data

> data = { "a": [1,2,3], "b":[11,12,13], "c":[31,32,33]}

So far, I could able to create a single list of combinations, Now I m kind of stuck here. how to add the other items on the list.

```
from itertools import combinations 
import datetime 
data = { "a": [1,2,3], "b":[11,12,13], "c":[31,32,33]}
for key, values in data.items():
    result = {}
    for iterate in range(len(values)):
        result["timegenerated"] = { int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()) } 
        comb = combinations(values,iterate+1)
        for i in list(comb):
            val_list = list(i)
            result[key] = { "in" :val_list }
            print(result)
        result = {}
```

Actual Output:

```
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'a': {'in': [1]}}
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'a': {'in': [2]}}
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'a': {'in': [3]}}
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'a': {'in': [1, 2]}}
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'a': {'in': [1, 3]}}
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'a': {'in': [2, 3]}}
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'a': {'in': [1, 2, 3]}}
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'b': {'in': [11]}}
.
.
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'c': {'in': [32, 33]}}
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'c': {'in': [31, 32, 33]}}
```

Expected Output:

> Actual Output +

```
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'a': {'in': [1]}}
.
.

{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'a': {'in': [1]},'b': {'in': [11]} }
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'a': {'in': [1]},'b': {'in': [12]} }
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'a': {'in': [1]},'b': {'in': [13]} }
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'a': {'in': [1]},'b': {'in': [11,12]} }
.
.
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'a': {'in': [1,2,3]},'b': {'in': [11,12,13]},'c': {'in': [31,32,33]} }
.
.
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'b': {'in': [11]} }
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'b': {'in': [12]} }

.
.
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'b': {'in': [11]},'c': {'in': [31]} }
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'b': {'in': [11]},'c': {'in': [31,32]} }

.
.

{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'b': {'in': [11,12,13]},'c': {'in': [31,32,33]} }

.
.

{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'c': {'in': [31]} }
{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'c': {'in': [32]} }
.
.

{'datetime': {1569988851}, 'c': {'in': [31,32]} }
```

Suggestions required to full fill the combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tweaked a little bit to get the result.

```
parsed_keys = []
for i in range(len(data.keys())):
    result = {}
    count = 0
    for key, values in data.items():
        if key not in parsed_keys:
            for iterate in range(len(values)):
                result["timegenerated"] = { int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()) } 
                comb = combinations(values,iterate+1)
                for i in list(comb):
                    val_list = list(i)
                    result[key] = { "in" :val_list }
                    print(result)
        if count == 0 and key not in parsed_keys:
            parsed_keys.append(key)
            count += 1
```

Comment: I can accept only after two days. will do that in 2 days

Answer (score 1):

The result dictionary gets reinitialised on every iteration of `for key, values in data.items():`

Hence, move the initialization of result outside the loop.

```
from itertools import combinations 
import datetime 
data = { "a": [1,2,3], "b":[11,12,13], "c":[31,32,33]}
result = {}
final = {}
for key, values in data.items():
    for iterate in range(len(values)):
        result["timegenerated"] = { int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()) } 
        comb = combinations(values,iterate+1)
        for i in list(comb):
            val_list = list(i)
            result[key] = { "in" :val_list }
print(result)
```

Comment: The Answer you've suggested will append to the existing list and will not cover the other columns(ie: it will append to the key "a".... it will not cover the "b" and "c" individually ... and b,c combinations, etc...

Comment: Did you run it?

Comment: yes. It prints {a:[1], ... {a:[1], b:[11]}..
but it does not take it to {b[11]}

Comment: I think I should add few more lines to the expected result. let me add.

Comment: Yes, the question needs bit more clarity.

Comment: thats great happy to help